# Twitter authentication problems

Tags: iphone, twitter

i am doing an application to upload photos and comments to twitter using twit pic.But when the user enter their twitter username and password,they give a pin number and the user have to enter this pin number everytime when he uses this application.Any way to overcome this problem of entering pin number all the time?please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the PIN is from the OAuth flow.  You can either:
A. Detect when the Twitter pin is displayed, do a screen-scrape for the PIN value, then do the necessary processing.

B. Use a custom value for your OAuth callback for example: oauth://callback and have your app handle the callback.  That way you don't have to use the out-of-band (PIN) flow.

Comment: I dont want to show the pin number to the user which the twitter provide.can i hide that pin number displaying page

Comment: You can try, but I think it will still be visible for a split-second.  If you don't want the user to see the PIN then use the custom callback.

Comment: thanks jcm, but what is the change in the code i have to make it as custom callback.i am newer to this field.help me please

Comment: Checkout the links posted by @richerd in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Mobile pin number auth flow is mainly intended for devices that don't have full keyboards or have limited web browsers (feature phones).

Add a parameter called oauth_callback when loading the login page and when the user logs in and web view finishes loading you can detect the callback url and extract the oauth_verifier key which can then be exchanged for OAuth Tokens that your application can save. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/oauth/access_token

For more information on login flow check out the twitter dev site: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth

Also you are targeting iOS 5 you can uses the built in Twitter.framework and TWTweetComposeViewController to send images directly to twitter.

P.S I'm the developer of HootSuite for iPhone / iPad. http://hootsuite.com/iphone

Comment: I dont want to show the pin number to the user which the twitter provide.can i hide that pin number displaying page

Comment: if you use the proper OAuth flow with the callback parameter then the pin number won't even be displayed. What will happen is that the user will be prompted to login, then once they put there username and password the login will show a success message and then redirect back to your app though the callback.